# How to use distance matrix in k-centroid clustering?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

The k-centroid clustering function takes in numeric data matrix as input. However, I have only distance matrix here, and I think k-centroid algorithm does work on distance matrix.

Exerpt from Official documentation

**Usage**

```
library(flexclust)
kcca(x, k, family=kccaFamily("kmeans"), weights=NULL, group=NULL,
     control=NULL, simple=FALSE)
```

**Arguments**

```
x    A numeric matrix of data, or an object that can be coerced to such a matrix (such as a numeric vector or a data frame with all numeric columns).
```

Specificly, I need to send a distance matrix into this kcca() function. But by the book, it takes in data matrix.

## Update

### Task

To cluster the rows of a binary matrix. Each row stands for a user.

### Data

The raw data is a 10^5 * 10^5 binary matrix like this

```
   1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8 ... 10^5
 _________________________
1| 0  0  1  0  1  1  1  0
2| 0  1  1  0  1  1  1  0
3| 0  0  0  1  0  1  1  0
4| 0  1  1  1  0  1  1  0
.
.
.
10^5
```

It is too large for R to procss, and my interest lies in the row clustering, so I calculate the row distance in Java and generate a distance matrix for R to read.

```
   1  2  3  4 ...
  ---------------
2| 2  
3| 1  3
4| 3  2  5
.
.
.
```

Then the problem is, [K-centroid](http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/flexclust/html/kcca.html) function in R takes in raw data matrix rather than distance matrix.

I hope this update helps.

Comment: Most distance matrices in R are not real matrices, so if you need a matrix you often need to coerce to one with `as.matrix`.

Comment: Yeah, that's a good point. But there is more than just problem of format. The function takes in raw data matrix and calculted the distance of rows. But my data is pre-calculated distance.

Comment: Be that as it may ... You offered no data, no code (only and extract from the help page) and no pointers to packages from which this help page extract was coming. If you know that calculating a distance matrix is the firsttask then you can probably figure out a way to insert a distance matrix in the right place.

Comment: I am a bit perplexed that you have problems to deal with a 1e5*1e5 binary matrix, but not with a 1e5*1e5 distance matrix (it only has half as many elements, but these are doubles).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

K-centroids needs to be able to compute **centroids**.

You probably wanted to use **k-medoids** aka `PAM` instead:

http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/cluster/html/pam.html

Here, clusters are represented by a central object of the original data vectors each ("medoid", similar to a median; but based on distances), instead of a mean vector ("centroid") as in k-means / k-centroids.

Comment: That's exacly what I need. And it seems that I confused K-medoids with k-centroids.